# Understanding public property list - C# MVC Best Practices

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm trying to figure out best coding practices and performance optimisation. I'm learning C# MVC and creating a picture project to put what I am learning to use. Here's the question.

I currently have

```
public long PictureID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string File { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Breed { get; set; }
    public DateTime Posted { get; set; }
```

But I'm thinking Category and Breed should be a list however I'm not sure where to implement it correctly.

```
public long PictureID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string File { get; set; }
    public List<Category> Animal { get; set; }
    public List<BreedType> Breed { get; set; }
    public DateTime Posted { get; set; }
```

The category would stay static as the values would be Dog Cat Bird Horse etc however the Breed would change depending on the Category selected

Do I list the category and breed options in the class or in a separate class?
On the other hand, should I create a table for each of the category breeds, like DogBreeds CatBreeds etc?

Thanks to anyone that can help.

Comment: Is this your view model?  Or is this somewhere else in your application?

Comment: Do you need a Dropdownlist drill through?

Answer (score 1):

You could have structure like this :
One to many relationship . for Category and breed

```
class Pic
{ 
public Pic()
{
Categories = new List();
}

    public long PictureID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string File { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Category> Categories{ get; set; }
    public DateTime Posted { get; set; }
}
```

make class for category and implement breed there .

```
class Category
{
public Category()
{
Breeds = new List();
}
public ICollection<Breed> Breeds {get;set;}
}
```

In this way you can achieve your relationship..
I hope this helps..

Comment: In Breed class u can implement ur breed id and category member

Answer (score 0):

I would organize the tables this way

```
Category
- Id
- Name

Breed
- Id
- Name
- CategoryId

Stuff
- PictureId
- UserId
- File
- BreedId
- Posted
```

And the models like this, why you want a List of Category or Breed?

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int Name {get;set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Breed> Breeds {get;set;}
}

public class Breed
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int Name {get;set;}
    public int CategoryId {get;set;}

    public virtual Category Category {get;set;}
}


public class Stuff
{
    public int PictureId {get;set;}
    public int UserId {get;set;}
    public string File {get;set;}
    public int BreedId {get;set;}
    public DateTime Posted {get;set;}

    public virtual Breed Breed {get;set;}
}
```

If I want the Category of the Breed I could do something like

```
stuff.Breed.Category.Name
```

If this is very verbose, create a ViewModel with the properties that matters and do a single query before...

Comment: Just a short question: why are you using virtual for the category and breed properties?

Comment: This is kinda the idea I had but wasn't too sure how to implement it. Thanks

Comment: @Jamie the virtual modifier is used thinking that EF will be used as the ORM http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232